# Git project with commits in both "master" and "main" branch

Tags: git

We have a current project with this structure:
[State of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM6AR.png).

The Dark purple branch is "master"

The Light purple branch is "main"

The presence of both these branches comes from the fact that we merged an old project, based on "master", into a new one, based on "main".

I would like to maintain the commits from both branches in a single "main" branch and delete the "master" branch.

Ideally, I imagine something like this: [Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F28PB.png)

While not new to git, I have never had to do "advance" operation, any idea what operations might be needed to clean this mess up?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing particularly advanced about this.

Merge the master branch into main, and then delete the master branch.

```
git checkout main
git merge master
git branch -d master
git push origin :master
```

The history might still show a divergence, but you should think of it similar to how a feature branch may still show like that in a graph view.

You'll have to coordinate with everyone that develops on this project about this change, which doesn't have a specific flavor of "how to do".